# How to disable Program Compatibility Assistent for using 3rd party themes?

Tags: windows-10, themes

I want to install [this Aero](https://www.deviantart.com/win7tbar/art/Windows-7-Theme-for-Windows-10-692706139) theme on Windows 10 version 21H2, build 19044.1288. When I run UxStyle installer, based on this guide: [How to install and apply third party themes in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/how-to-install-and-apply-third-party-themes-in-windows-10/), I get:

[image: Issue popup]

(NOTE that clicking *Learn more* leads to nowhere, it leads to the index of the Microsoft docs.)

I've gone to Services app and set it up so that Program Compatibility Assistant is stopped and is not automatically started on system startup, and applied the changes. So, I tried running UxStyle installer again and it shows the same popup above. I restarted Windows 10 and the same issue happened.

[image: Service setting]

Comment: "UxStyle is a bit of software that relaxes Windows theme signature requirements to enable third-party customization. " In other words, UxStyle is **designed to reduce Windows security.** Perhaps a newer version might run in Windows, but is it that important to you to have a theme that *does not meet Windows security requirements?*

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I trust this UxStyle software, based on the tutorial. I tried something similiar on Windows 11 and it didn't work, so I downgraded  to Windows 10 (which my PC came with). Newer version? Will look.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Just looked at https://uxstyle.com and I've seen the setup I downloaded is the latest one. I also noted it's for Windows 10 Technical Preview. I'm afraid I can't get Windows 10 TP to run in my laptop because of driver issues.

Comment: The fact that it spammed me with requirements to click on stuff when accessing the page makes it immediately sus in my book.

Comment: Windows 10 Technical Preview is a beta version. Much has changed since then. And did you consider the possibility that this theme now has malware (even if it didn't whenever it was first published)?